# left arrow key turns on keycode 37 and 39

Tags: keycode, arrow-keys

I am trying to program a simple pong program that uses arrow keys to navigate the player's paddle. I need to check instantaneous keycodes so I made a separate js file to parse the onkeydown and onkeyup events as booleans for the keycodes that I need. However, when I type the left arrow it turns on keycodes 37 and 39 together. This doesn't work for the right arrow but I have had it before confuse the space bar as an arrow key. The code basically looks like this:

```
    var KeyPressed=
    {
        Left:false,
        Right:false,
        ...
    };

    window.onkeydown =function(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        var getKey = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode:e.charCode;
        switch (getKey) {
            case  37: KeyPressed.Left=true;
            case  39: KeyPressed.Right=true;
            ...
        }
    };

    window.onkeyup = function(e){
        e = e || window.event;
        var getKey = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode:e.charCode;
        switch (getKey){
            case  37: KeyPressed.Left=false;
            case  39: KeyPressed.Right=false;
            ...
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're not resetting the left/right boolean status per press. So you should probably `onkeyup` set both to false regardless.

Comment: no they both reset alright, it's just for some reason left arrow does 37 and 39, and right arrow just does 39. I'm thinking it might have something to do with the character encoding maybe? like it has keycode and it has charcode function. I may have used it wrong. This is the only way I can find out how to code it online though and it works for them. But this doesn't work for me and my friend when I sent it to him. I can override it if its just this one key pattern, but it has been doing other things too like left affecting the space bar that I'm using as a temp, debug pause.